# Maven import issue, at complie time milestone version is getting used but at runtime latest RELEASE version is getting used

Tags: java, maven-3, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have below `RC` release of the dependency declared into my `POM.xm` file. At compile time the `RC` version is used but at runtime `RELEASE` version is getting used which results into `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

This adds both `4.1.0-RC1` and `4.0.3.RELEASE` to the classpath.

`SearchHit#getIndex` got introduced in `4.1.x` release which is still into milestone. Here is the complete `pom.xml` of this maven module(removed other dependencies):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>search</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

It's a multi-module spring boot project using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.3.3.RELEASE`.
Where could be the issue? I am using Intellij IDEA

Update:

1. If I delete the `spring-data-elasticsearch` from this "search" module, both versions gets deleted from the project
2. I am using this "search" module into "rest" module. I ran `mvn dependency:tree` and the resulting log is surprising. The "search" module has the `4.1.0-RC1` version but in "rest" module where "search" is imported and no addtional presence of elasticsearh dependency, `4.0.3.RELEASE` is coming.

From "search" module:
[image: search module has RC version]

From "rest" module where I have used "search" dependency
[image: rest module brining RELEASE version]

This single dependency is responsible for adding two versions. And removing it removes both the dependencies. Weird.
[image]

Comment: what do you have as dependencies in the parent pom? Have you run `mvn dependency:tree` to see where the dependencies are pulled in?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch please see the update.

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1.0-RC1 has Spring 5.3.0-RC1 as dependency, there is something pretty mixed up in your dependencies

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Tried everything but last option was to update the spring boot version to `2.4.0-M3` but provide `2.4.0-M3` into `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`

Comment: in my test setup I use for development I have a boot parent of 2.3.3.RELEASE and use Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1.0-SNAPSHOT without problems. But not as a multi-project setup

Comment: @P.J.Meisch could be config issues with multi maven. Any expected date for the next `RELEASE` version?

Comment: Wait, how did you used `4.1.0-SNAPSHOT`? The latest is `4.1.0-RC1`.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/releases

Comment: first, there is a snapshot repository (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#preface.metadata), second, as I am a contributor, I always have the latest snapshot on my machine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

4.1.0-RC1 and 4.0.3-RELEASE are two completely different versions.  Odds are that you depend on two items, which both in turn depend on two different versions of the same item.

This sometimes happens when a person wants to use a library at a version that's newer than the reset of the system.  This new version makes the old non-updated versions incompatible with putting all your classes into one ClassLoader.

The solution is is decide which version of elasticsearch you want to use (the older one or the newer one), and then to adjust the other library's version number to see if you can find an older or newer version that depends on the desired elasticsearch library.  Sometimes this adjustment means you have to adjust other libraries too, to get a consistent set of dependencies.

There are other approaches; but, the above approach is the best.  It doesn't need any additional knowledge or framework, is compatible with standard JAR loaders, and in a day's experimentation, often you have have a workign set of JAR files.

Note that since you are using a Release Candidate version of elasticsearch, odds are that many of the JARs you are using might not be released in a stable version against this "not yet released" version of elasticsearch.  You might have to find release candidate versions of the other JARS, beta versions, alpha versions, or if all else fails, you might have to create a version.  These items are all out-of-scope for this discussion; but, they should provide you with strong reasons to consider the possible difficulties of choosing the 4.1.0-RC1 version as the one you want to keep.

Comment: Yes, I have elasticsearch config class into my "rest" module. **But** imports there exists both in `4.0.3-RELEASE` and `4.1.0-RC1` and under the same package. Does it still matter?